# Add column to migration when using compound model name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called MyArticle. When I try to use the command

```
rails generate migration AddtestToMyArticle test:string
```

the migration file contains only empty up/down methods. Having done this previously on a single word model name, it worked just fine and the migration up/down methods had the appropriate code.

I tried "AddtestToMy_Article" but that didn't work either. What do I need to do to work with my compound model name and the generate migration command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
rails generate migration AddColumnToMyArticle test:string
```

When using 'AddColumn' you will have the appropriate code in your migration.

I just looked back over this, and while my answer is correct, it's better to have a more descriptive migration name. The user below who noticed the capitalization is right in that if you don't have each new word capitalized, Rails won't pick up on what exactly you're trying to do. So, in your question you have `AddtestTo...` but it should be `AddTestTo...`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work if you use underscores rather than CamelCase

```
rails g migration add_test_to_my_article test:string
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

rails generate migration AddNewFieldToMyArticle new_field:string

Comment: In other words: Please note the capital N in NewField.

Comment: No, the field name is not the problem, my model name is. Let's say I'm adding a field called 'test'. It has the same problem. I only used 'new field' in my question as an example.